# Can't assign object to literal types

Tags: typescript

```
  interface IOptions {
    foo: 'bar';
  }

  const example = (opts: IOptions) => console.log(opts);

  const options = { foo: 'bar' };

  example(options); // Argument of type '{ foo: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IOptions'. Types of property 'foo' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"bar"'.
  example({ foo: 'bar' }); // runs fine
```

As you can see I passed same exact object, but if I define it first it's doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @pzaenger it's works, thanks. Still weird what you need to do it.

Comment: but what if I have `example` function and  `IOptions` in other file, there is no way to do it without exporting stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) for `foo` property:

```
foo: 'bar';
```

> String literal types allow you to specify the exact value a string must have

This means that `foo` can hold **only** `'bar'` value (not any `string`).

Type of `options` is resolved to `{ foo: string }` because `foo` is mutable. If you want to force typescript to infer literal type, you can use [`as const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const options = { foo: 'bar' } as const; // type is { readonly foo: "bar"; }
example(options); // no error now
```

Another option is specifying the type explicitly:

```
const options: IOptions = { foo: 'bar' };
```

---

If you want to allow `foo` to accept any `string`, change the definition to:

```
interface IOptions {
  foo: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the type of options. Because just by defining the const it is not guaranteed that your defined will continue to have the same signature, you can add or remove keys at any point of time as it is not explicitly defined with any type it can raise an error.

```
interface IOptions {
    foo: 'bar';
}

const example = (opts: IOptions) => console.log(opts);

const options: IOptions = { foo: 'bar' }; // define type here
const options2 = { foo: 'bar' };

example(options); 
example(options2 as IOptions) // If you are sure that options 2 is correct type
example({ foo: 'bar' });
```

Comment: but what if I have `example` function and  `IOptions` in other file, there is no way to do it without exporting stuff?

Comment: For example if I'm making npm package and want to use literal types so users will know that they can pass as options, but I don't want to force them to export `IOptions` or write their own interface